# How to (re)move the Spaces Toolbar button?

Tags: thunderbird, toolbar

The button in Thunderbird 102 is in the upper left corner with no obvious way to move it or remove it completely. Is there a way to get rid of it so that when I move the mouse cursor to the upper left corner, I click on the Inbox tab of my mailbox instead of that button?

Comment: point at toolbar=> customize=> drag

Comment: This doesn't do anything for me. A menu with 4 color settings pops up, but that's it, I'm not able to drag anything, not even the window with the color settings.

Comment: Go to "View" menu, "Toolbars", and uncheck "Spaces Toolbar".

Comment: That hides the toolbar itself, but leaves the button. I want the button gone too, or at least moved away.

Comment: @Intri sorry, you mean the “spaces menu”… Then I don't know how it can be hidden, except when the “spaces toolbar” is shown…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your userchrome.css:

```
  #spacesPinnedButton{
  display: none

  }
```

After you did the following:

1. Access the Config Editor in TB, go to Tools > Options or do Thunderbird > Preferences

Add toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets with value true.

2. Locate your profile folder usually at C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\xxxxxxxx.default-release\

There should be a folder here called "chrome", if not, make a new folder with that name.

In this folder you should add your userchrome.css file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! The only other thing I had to do was to enable the toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets settings in the Config Editor, but that's true for all tweaks via the userChrome.css file to work.

Comment: @Intri, No problem, should've clarified you needed that but didn't have time to type it out at that very moment. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me, too. And seems to have no side effect.
As much as I like Thunderbird, UI changes that are not necessary are a pain in... . Why can't this be optional or easy to configure?

If you have come here and do not know how to use this tweak: Go to your Thunderbird profile folder (where, e.g., the abook.sqlite file is stored) and - if not existing - create the folder 'chrome' and in there the file 'userChrome.css' with the content above.